# Using apply to add multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to run a function (row_extract) over a column in my dataframe, that returns three values that I then want to add to three new columns.

I've tried running it like this

```
all_data["substance", "extracted name", "name confidence"] = all_data["name"].apply(row_extract)
```

but I get one column with all three values.  I'm going to iterate over the rows, but that doesn't seem like a very efficient system - any thoughts?

This is my current solution, but it takes an age.

```
for index, row in all_data.iterrows():
    all_data.at[index, "substance"], all_data.at[index, "extracted name"], all_data.at[index, "name confidence"]  = row_extract(row["name"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Check what the type of your function output is or what the datatypes are. It seems like that's a string.

You can use the "split" method on a string to separate them.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html

Alternatively, adjust your function to return more than one value.

E.g.

```
def myfunc():
    ...
    ...
    return x, y, z
```

Comment: So that bit is fine, the issue is how I get the results to be assigned to separate columns in my data frame.

Comment: try double brackets, like this: all_data[["substance", "extracted name", "name confidence"]]

Comment: Annoyingly not - got an error, but not sure what it was.  My iteration solution above still best.